# Kernel Explanation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

sorry for asking so many questions lately but our lecturer is doing a terrible job explaining things.

Calculate $ker(A)$ given that:

$f:\{\mathbb{R}^3→\mathbb{R}^3; r→ A\vec{r}\}$

$A= \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
 1&2  &4 \\ 
 0&1  &2 \\ 
 3&1  &2 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$

I have been browsing the web for some answers but I don't really get it. Maybe someone can explain what the kernel is and how I calculate it. I hope my question makes sense. I had to translate it since I am studying at a german university.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $4$ questions is not that many.  Feel free to ask as many more as you like.

Comment: Yeah, as long as you post questions that end with "this is the thing that I tried" or "this is the particular thing I don't understand", ask as many as you want.

Comment: Thanks guys! All of your answers were really helpful!

Comment: @Rzeta If you're having a hard time figuring out the kernel of a matrix, then you probably don't have down the $4$ fundamental subspaces and how they relate to each other.  Here are a couple of relatively short pdf's that might help: [here](http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/Essays/newpaper_ver3.pdf) and [here](http://www.engineering.iastate.edu/~julied/classes/CE570/Notes/strangpaper.pdf).

Comment: We started linear algebra last week. No joke. The way math is taught here is pretty terrible. I am looking forward to christmas not because I can relax but because I finally have the time to work through Gilbert Strangs Linear Algebra book. Thankyou for the pdf's. Are they from his book?

Comment: @Rzeta They're from his class.  I don't know if he literally copied them from his book or not.  Also, if you don't put on @ symbol in front of someone's name (assuming that person isn't the questioner/ answerer), they aren't alerted to the fact that you are responding to them. ;)

Comment: @Bye_World Oops. Well now I know ;) Thanks again. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solve the homogeneous system, which means reducing the matrix by rows, say:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&4\\
0&1&2\\3&1&2\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_3-3R_1}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&2&4\\
0&1&2\\0&\!\!-5&\!\!-10\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_3+5R_2}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&2&4\\
0&1&2\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

The above means

$$\begin{align}&x_2+2x_3=0\implies x_2=-2x_3\\
&x_1+2x_2+4x_3=0\implies x_1=-2(-2x_3)-4x_3=0\end{align}$$

and thus the kernel is

$$\left\{\;\begin{pmatrix}0\\-2t\\t\end{pmatrix}\;\;:\;\;\;t\in\Bbb R\;\right\}$$

Comment: So just to clarify: I am looking for some vector (the set of vectors) that, when multiplied with the matrix A, gives me the zero matrix. Is that correct?

Comment: The zero *vector*.

Comment: True. If I multiply them it will give me a vector. Thankyou

Answer (score 4):

The kernel of a linear transformation is the set of vectors that it sends to 0. Thus the goal is to find all solutions $v$ of
$$Av=0$$
This can be done with Gaussian elimination.

Comment: I forgot to thank you for your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Rzeta You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The kernel is the set $\{\vec r : A \vec r = \vec 0\}$. You can determine all solutions using e.g. row reduction.